# Xcode 10: Auto insert closing braces bug

Tags: swift, xcode10

In Xcode (swift file), I'm facing an issue where automatic insertion of closing brace is not working anymore.

Ex: when I write

```
func myFunc() {
```

and hit Enter, Xcode will not insert the closing brace, and I need to do it by myself (and I'm very angry about it...)

Yet, my settings seem to be good:
Preferences -> Text Editing tab -> "automatically insert closing braces" == true

It seems to happen for each file containing commented code, especially this (very common) piece of comment : `//}`

Configuration: Xcode Version 10.0 (10A255)

Steps to reproduce on a new Playground:

1. Copy and paste the following comment : `//}`
2. Then type : `func test() {`
3. Then hit enter

It definitely seems to be a bug in the text editor. Already filed with Apple bug reporter.

Can everyone  reproduce the bug or is it due to some configs ? And if so, what can I do to fix it ?

Comment: I experienced that as well, but cannot tell exactly under what circumstances. Sometimes re-indenting the source file (cmd-a, ctrl-i) helps.

Comment: Ok. Can you reproduce my modus operandi ?

Comment: In Xcode 10.2 the bug is still there and related to commented code

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was fixed by Apple in Xcode 10.1 (10B61)

Comment: Xcode 10.1 still have the problem. After creating new class file, the closing brace wont appear automatically.

Comment: I'm using XCode 10.2.1, still issue exists.

Comment: Bug still exist in Xcode 11.3.1. The solution was replacing block comments with line comments.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Xcode 10.3.  I've discovered if I have comment blocks in a file, then Xcode won't auto insert a closing bracket in that file.

```
/*
Temporary fix.  Replace this...
*/

//
// ...with this
//
```

Comment: This was the issue for me as well (Xcode Version 11.3 (11C29))